# How to share controls while watching YouTube videos on Skype

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, skype, youtube

Using two Windows machines is it possible somehow to share the control of a YouTube video while it's playing? If I'd like to share video I could just send the link, however sender and receiver wouldn't control together the video.

What I'd like to do is basically to be able to send a YouTube link via Skype, and also I'd like to be able, for instance, if I do a rewind a rewind should be done on the other machine as well, or a stop, etc.

Is there anything you could suggest to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to share your screen and audio using something like [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/) which has a presentation mode for sharing your screen and audio to another person.

Check out the "Online Meetings" video on [this page](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/support/videos/) to see how to use Teamviewer

I prefer to use an audio mixer such as [Voicemeter](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/index.htm) which allows me to send both my computer's audio and audio from my microphone while in a Skype call, and use Skype's inbuilt screen sharing for the visuals.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6rp9lkiFBU) shows how you can mix computer and microphone audio using voicemeter, so that the other person can hear both you and the video in a Skype call.

Both of these options are free at time of writing.

Comment: Could you share any kind of tutorial on the subject?

Comment: Sure thing, I have added some links, if anything is't clear feel free to ask

Comment: So you do suggest to use team viewer ONLY to share the screen, together with that I should also run skype with Voicemeter, is that correct?

Comment: Teamviewer can also share audio from your PC and microphone, so its an all in one option. It does, however, mean that the other person will hear their own voice when they speak and your are sending your computer's audio, which is why I prefer the second option, although it is more complicated.

Comment: So, again, I should use them together in order to avoid the inconvenience you just pointed out.

Comment: In that case, you would only need Skype (to share the screen) and Voicemeter (to share your computer's audio), Teamviewer wold not be necessary.

Comment: How do I share screen via skype?

Comment: Aha, now I understand your confusion! See [here](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa10022/how-do-i-share-my-screen-in-skype)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that so thanks. But only one of the two would be able to control the computer, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Teamviewer's "Remote Control" feature would allow both of you to control the video, as well as hear and see it, so if that's important then Teamviewer is the better option. It might be easier for the other party to simply ask you to rewind or pause, but that's up to you.